# Connect (Bind) database to WPF application

Tags: wpf, database, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012-express

I have created a front end application in WPF (VS2012) and I have to connect a database to it.

Do not know how to connect SQL database with WPF application. Kindly guide me

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Comment: microsoft sql server express edition 2012,

Comment: @marc_s I have database and just i need to know how to connect wpf and database... help me with it

Comment: You have tons of options: "raw" ADO.NET which just is basic SQL statements and deals with (untyped) rows and columns, or you can use something like Entity Framework to have EF "translate" those DB tables into .NET objects for you (much easier to work with later on)

Comment: [This article here shows](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=558) how to use Entity Framework with WPF

Comment: in VS2012 ADO.NET is not supported....  have to go with entity framework

Comment: **OFF COURSE** ADO.NET is supported! What makes you think that??? You have the entire `System.Data` and `System.Data.SqlClient` namespaces in .NET 4.5 - that's your whole ADO.NET right there!